# IE11 - LOSING MY COOKIES: 302 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, cookies, https, internet-explorer-11

Using IE11 I am making a get request to SITE A:

```
GET http://www.test.com/?documentId=ef746317-7711-4458-8873-a73700fc1b85 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: www.test.com
```

I receive a redirect with 2 cookies:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 23:48:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://www.newSite.com/test/Edit/ef746317-7711-4458-8873-a73700fc1b85
Set-Cookie: Auth=EAAAAIQfMoK32BNjBypXapcJppWc==; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: Auth=EAAAAN+xPT6eioV8LESTR6CViGIvc834gP==; path=/; secure
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR IVAi IVDi OUR TST"
Content-Length: 0
```

IE would appear to be following the redirect and does a GET, but as you can see is not sending back the cookies:

```
GET https://www.newSite.com/test/Edit/ef746317-7711-4458-8873-a73700fc1b85 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: www.newSite.com
```

And then of course is the 401:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 23:48:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
<HTML>Blah blah blah access denied error</HTML>
```

I tried adding the P3P headers to force IE to send the cookies in the redirect but no dice.  I have read there may be an issue with IE sending cookies in redirect when going from HTTP to HTTPS, or because the "secure" cookies are being sent back to the browser on HTTP which when redirects to HTTP sees the different domain and chokes.  I cannot change the web sites as they are vendors, but I can alter the 302 being sent back to IE11 with the interface middle-ware I am working on. Any thoughts on how I can trick/force IE to send back these cookies on the redirect?

Update 1:  I have tried Firefox 52, IE11, and Chrome.  No browser is accepting that 302 and sending the get back with the cookies. Someone out there must understand how redirects with cookies work.  No responses makes me wonder if this site is reaching the right people.

Answer (score 0):

I got around my issue with sort of a hack.  Since the browser would not forward cookies back in a 302 redirect, I just send back a little page that does the posting for me, instead of my interface software.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirect</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://testAPI.test.com/" method="POST">
<input name="UserName" value="Test APIUser"/>
<input name="UserEmail" value="test@test.com"/>
<input name="PatientId" value="1d11eb2e-2606-485e-ad5d-a70c00daa37a"/>
<input name="Timestamp" value="Mon, 20 Mar 2017 19:11:24 GMT"/>
84c6-a7210111648b"/>
<input name="Token" value="MRVp/pBRBJ08F8cYMavfL8 ="/>
</form>
<script language="javascript"> window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Protected Mode. Protected Mode is designed to prevent malicious software from exploiting vulnerabilities in Internet Explorer 11. This mode may also block cookies depending on the current setup.

Open Internet Explorer 11.
Click Tools and then select Internet options.
Go to Security tab.
Under Security level for this zone, clear the check box for Enable Protected Mode (requires restarting Internet Explorer).
Click OK.
Close Internet Explorer 11 and then launch it again.